# Excel 2010: How to change pivot table source data without disconnecting slicers?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have researched like mad about this, and I'm worried there isn't an answer. But maybe the really smart people on this site can help.

I have two workbooks that work together - Charts.xlsm and Data.xlsm. They are always kept together in the same folder. The Charts.xlsm obviously contains all of my charts, but they are all linked to tables in Data.xlsm for their source. I also have lots of slicers in my Charts.xlsm that are connected to the charts, and they share caches when they are connected to charts with the same data source. The two workbooks are always open at the same time so that the data source reference looks like this: 'Data.xlsm'!Table1

This all works great, until I put these workbooks on another computer (which is why I am doing this so I need to find out how to fix this).

Once the workbooks are closed, the source data references change to a specific location on my harddrive: 'C:\Folder\Data.xlsm'!Table1

If I want to manually change this back to a local reference, I have to first go through and disconnect every single slicer, refresh the tables, then reconnect every slicer. Not a viable solution for my clients.

I would use VBA to change the references every time Charts.xlsm is open, but when I tried it one of two things would happen: either the workbook produced errors that would prevent saving, or Excel would crash completely.

This is the code that works perfectly for disconnecting the slicers, but produces the 'save' error:

```
Sub Disconnect_Slicers()

Dim oSliceCache As SlicerCache
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim i As Long

For Each oSliceCache In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(oSliceCache.Name).PivotTables
        For i = .Count To 1 Step -1
            .RemovePivotTable (.Item(i))
        Next i
    End With
Next oSliceCache

End Sub
```

So... I am asking the Excel/VBA geniuses out there if there is any way I can maintain a relative location for my charts when they are looking for Data.xlsm so that no matter what computer I open those workbooks on, they will always be actively linked.

Thank you SO much in advance!

Comment: Warning! The `Disconnect_Slicers()` sub actually wrecked my Excel program - now nothing will save. I have no idea how something so small could have destroyed Excel's inner workings, but it has. So... caution is advised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If always both files are in the same folder you could possibly go this way.

A. Switch off auto 'UpdateLinks' of Chart.xlsm file. You could do this once manually or, for safety reason, always when `BeforeClose` event fires to avoid some possible problems:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
End Sub
```

B. When you open Chart.xlsm change the link to Data.Xlsm using Workbook Open event + additionally refresh links. In this situation we check path to Chart.Xlsm file and search Data.Xlsm in the same folder. I assume that there is only one link to any other file otherwise some changes could be required:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'changing first and only one link to new one
Dim a
a = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
    ThisWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=a(1), _
        NewName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Data.xlsm", Type:=xlExcelLinks    
'update the link
ThisWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=a(1), Type:=xlExcelLinks
End Sub
```

I admit I do not consider all the risks therefore some test are required.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly! Thank you so much! I love learning new things about Excel :)